# How to change datatype in code of an XML file's element?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I have a strongly typed xml data file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<PRODUCTS>
  <xs:schema id="PRODUCTS" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
    <xs:element name="PRODUCTS" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="PRODUCT" msprop:REFCursorName="REFCursor">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PROD_DESC" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PRICE" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

```
  <PRODUCT>
    <PROD_DESC>Chips</PROD_DESC>
    <PRICE>METRIC</PRICE>
   <PRODUCT>
```

What I want to do is change the element type from string to decimal in C# code. Does anyone know how I can achieve this. The problem is that this xml is generated from a view which I cannot change at the moment and I would like to modify the xml file before its read by a dataset in my code. Help.

Comment: You want change the **PRICE** element datatype from **string** to **decimal**. Right?

Comment: Please update your XSD & XML properly.

Comment: Yes I do want to change from string to decimal. The price tag should be something like : <PRICE>10.00</PRICE>